# using variable from .js file to .cs file

Tags: javascript, c#, database, mongodb, variables

Im programming in Visual Code C#, i'm making a chat application in SignalR, i want to store messages in a database in MongoDB. I need a help, that how can I use the 'message' and the 'user' variable from chat.js file in the Pogram.cs?

**chat.js**

```js
"use strict";

var connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder().withUrl("/chatHub").build();

//Disable send button until connection is established
document.getElementById("sendButton").disabled = true;

connection.on("ReceiveMessage", function (user, message) {
    var msg = message.replace(/&/g, "&amp;").replace(/</g, "&lt;").replace(/>/g, "&gt;");
    var encodedMsg = user + ": " + msg;
    var li = document.createElement("li");
    li.textContent = encodedMsg;
    document.getElementById("messagesList").appendChild(li);
});

connection.start().then(function () {
    document.getElementById("sendButton").disabled = false;
}).catch(function (err) {
    return console.error(err.toString());
});

document.getElementById("sendButton").addEventListener("click", function (event) {
    var user = document.getElementById("userInput").value;
    var message = document.getElementById("messageInput").value;
    connection.invoke("SendMessage", user, message).catch(function (err) {
        return console.error(err.toString());
    });
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

**Program.cs**

```css
namespace bcwebchat
{

    public class Message{
    public DateTime Sent;
    public string Msg;
}


public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            var client = new MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017");

            var db = client.GetDatabase("DemoInsert");

            var collec = db.GetCollection<Message>("DemoInsert");

            collec.InsertOne(new Message
            {
                Sent = DateTime.Now,
                Msg = "blaaahahaah"
            });
```

I want to use the user and the message in here:

```js
collec.InsertOne(new Message 
{
    Sent = DateTime.Now,
    Msg = "blaaahahaah"
});
```

Comment: I'm not sure if exactly what you want to do is possible. Are you familiar with WebMethods or making AJAX calls in C#?

Comment: not really, i am studiing c# and i'm not learning java and databases, all i want to do just insert into my MongoDB the username and the message, idk is it possible or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just following this section [Microsoft SignalR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/signalr?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio)
First, you should create a ASP.NET Web Application
Then, create a **ChatHub** and insert message, it should work

```
public class ChatHub : Hub
{
    public async Task SendMessage(string user, string message)
    {
            // insert your message to database
            collec.InsertOne(new Message 
            {
                Sent = DateTime.Now,
                Msg = message
            });
            await Clients.All.SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", user, message);
    }
}
```

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
     services.AddRazorPages();
     services.AddSignalR();
}
```

```
 public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
 {
      //some code here

      app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
      {
          endpoints.MapRazorPages();
         endpoints.MapHub<ChatHub>("/chatHub");
      });
}
```

Comment: That was helpful, that was, what i wanted, and its working, thank you